# UILocalNotification click event

Tags: iphone, ios

my code is :

```
- (void) socketIO:(SocketIO *)socket didReceiveEvent:(SocketIOPacket *)packet
{
NSLog(@"didReceiveEvent(),%@",packet.data );



SysNotification *sysNotification=[GlobalVariable parseSysNotificationWithString:packet.data];


UILocalNotification *alarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (alarm) {
    alarm.fireDate = [NSDate date];
    alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    alarm.repeatInterval = 0;
    alarm.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    alarm.alertBody = @"Test message...";

    NSDictionary *infoDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"name" forKey:@"key"];
    alarm.userInfo = infoDic;


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:alarm];
}


}
```

i want to when i click the UILocalNotification at the status bar,i can come to  some view controller.how to do?thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two scenarios to handle Local Notification,

**1. Application is launched because of clicking Local notification**

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UILocalNotification *localNotif =

        [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    if (localNotif) {

       //load your controller

    }

    return YES;

}
```

**2. Application is active** , then add this code in the AppDelegate

```
   -(void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {

        //load your controller

    }
```

Comment: when i at 1 Application is launched because of clicking Local notification.how to check different kinds of notification?

Comment: Different Kind of notification in the sense??

Comment: i have many notication: a b c. how to check if a is click.when i at  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions methods

Comment: localNotif.userInfo will give you an dictionary, you can get the value from that. In your case you should differentiate from the values [localNotif.userInfo objectForKey:@"key"];