# UILocalNotification not appear in iOS7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, ios7, uilocalnotification

I'm using UILocalNotification in my project. My code:

```
        UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notification.fireDate = event.date;
        notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];        

        notification.hasAction = YES;
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        [notification setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber+1];

        notification.alertBody = @"test alert body";

        notification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;

        NSLog(@"SCHEDULED NOTIFICATION  = %@", notification);

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

In time when notification should appear nothing is happen but application's badge icon value get +1. For iOS6 it's work fine. Where can be a problem?

***UPDATE*** I do not get any alerts about notification while my app is run and when it's closed. Ony badge number is changing.

Comment: Please check in background mode...

Comment: see so answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081210/uilocalnotification-click-event?rq=1

Comment: are you getting callback in didReceiveLocalNotification method?

Comment: Or is you Notification style for the is none in you setting menu?

Comment: @Deepesh waht do you mean?

Comment: UILocalNotification only fire when in app backgound mode....if you want to show the UILocalNotification in forground mode...use the didReceiveLocalNotification fuction

Comment: @Prine in all cases. On iOS6 when app was running I got alert from status bar and then app was closed I got standard notification alert. But now I get nothing.

Comment: @Deepesh but what about case when app is not running at all?

Comment: My app work in Both ios 7 and Ios 6

Comment: Please check it on the other device. Looks like your device has notifications disables for your app. Please check it out in Settings - Notifications

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it in the foreground often the `didReceiveLocalNotification` is missing:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]   objectForKey:@"CFBundleName"]
                                                        message:notification.alertBody
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alertView show];

    // Reset badges if you want
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you make sure that the app was considered to be in foreground - Nowhere is mentioned

Comment: Yeah you're right. I can't know that. It was an assumption because I once had a similar problem not showing the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround for this issue (https://devforums.apple.com/message/900205)

Just schedule the notification with some miliseconds of delay. In my case (messaging app) it work pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible issue is just that you declined push notifications from the app already. Even  though it says "Allow Push Notifications" the pop-up actually controls ALL notifications; push and local.

Just be sure to check your settings->notification center->your app name. I wasted an hour trying to figure out what went wrong when it turned out I just disabled push -_-